# CSS3 create this button using only single DIV

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to create a button similar to this in CSS3. (all HTML5 browsers should be supported):

Button image

[image: button image]

HTML:

```
<div class="buttonClass">Nitin Mukesh</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
        background:     gray;
        margin-top:     50px;
        margin-left:        50px;
}
.buttonClass {
    width:          300px;
    height:         40px;
    padding:        10px 60px;
    -webkit-border-radius:  7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius:      7px;
    background:     -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #91BDD6 100%); /* firefox */
    border:         solid #91BDD6 5px;
    outline:        solid #fff 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 1px 24px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 1px 24px #000000;
    box-shadow: 3px 1px 24px #000000;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyzw8/)

I could possible think of a solution that using 2 div will solve the problem with outer div hold the white outline and box-shadow and inner div with outline and gradient color.

Is it possible to achieve this using single div.

Many thanks for any inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow) can have multiple shadow, so:

http://jsfiddle.net/cyzw8/4/

```css
.buttonClass {
    width:          200px;
    height:         40px;
/*  padding:        10px 60px;*/
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
    border-radius:      7px;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#FFF 0%,#91BDD6 100%);
    background-image:       -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #91BDD6 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#FFF,#91BDD6);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#FFF,#91BDD6);
    background-image:linear-gradient(top,#FFF,#91BDD6);
    border:         solid #91BDD6 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #fff, 5px 3px 12px #000000;
}
```

This is what I see in my Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/heGu9/2/

```
.button
{
    display: block;

    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(145,189,214) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(145,189,214) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(145,189,214) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(145,189,214) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(145,189,214) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0, rgb(145,189,214)),
        color-stop(1, rgb(255,255,255))
    );

    /* Added second shadow for that "black" effect */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px white, 0px 0px 10px 5px black;
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px white, 0px 0px 10px 5px black;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px white, 0px 0px 10px 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px white, 0px 0px 10px 5px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px white, 0px 0px 10px 5px black;

    border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;

    border: solid 5px rgb(145,189,214);

    padding: 60px;

    margin: 7px; /* to complement the outside shadow */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs however this does not show the shadow effect (in black with alpha) as referred in image. Please ignore the background image sue to which it is less visible.

    http://jsfiddle.net/heGu9/1/

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the shadow. For the shadow, just add another one: http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/heGu9/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a second way http://jsfiddle.net/Merec/Va4qG/

```
<div class="buttonClass"><span>Nitin Mukesh</span></div>
```

```css
.buttonClass {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(145,189,214,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(145,189,214,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(145,189,214,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(145,189,214,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(145,189,214,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(145,189,214,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#91bdd6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.buttonClass span {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #91bdd6;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs however this does not show the shadow/glow effect (in black with alpha) as referred in image. Please ignore the background image sue to which it is less visible.

    http://jsfiddle.net/Va4qG/1/